# Trouble understanding React setState asychronicity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm having an issue with a React app I'm writing, and I think it stems from the asynchronicity of `setState()`. My code looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import TextDisplay from './TextDisplay';
import Dropdown from './Dropdown';

const langs = {
arabic: ['ا', 'ب', 'غ', 'ج', 'ذ', 'د', 'ه', 'ة', 'و', 'ز', 
'ح', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ي', 'خ', 'ك', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'س', 'ع', 'ف', 
'ص', 'ض', 'ق', 'ر', 'ش', 'س', 'ت', 'ث', 'ّ', 'أُ', 'إ', 'أ', 
'ئ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ِ', 'ُ', ' ', '\n'],
judeoArabic: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ג֔', 'ד', 'דּ', 'ה', 'ה֕', 'ו', 'ז', 
'ח', 'ט', 'ט֔', 'י', 'כ', 'כּ', 'ל', 'מ', 'נ', 'ס', 'ע', 'פ', 'צ', 
'צ֔', 'ק', 'ר', 'שׁ', 'ס', 'תּ', 'ת', '֝', 'ו', 'י', 'א', 'אְי', 'ינ', 
'אנ', 'י', 'ו', ' ', '\n']
};

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {value: '',
  displayValue: '',
  inLang: '',
  outLang: ''
  };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSet = this.handleSet.bind(this);
  this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
  this.handleInLang = this.handleInLang.bind(this);
  this.handleOutLang = this.handleOutLang.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({value: e.target.value});
}

handleSet(inLang, outLang, letter, indices, display) {
  indices = [];
  display = [];
  inLang = this.state.inLang;
  outLang = this.state.outLang;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.value.length; i ++) {
    letter = this.state.value.charAt(i);
    indices.push(langs.inLang.indexOf(letter));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < indices.length; i ++) {
    display.push(langs.outLang[indices[i]]);
  }
  this.setState({displayValue: display.join('')});
}

handleClear() {
  this.setState({displayValue: ''});
}

handleInLang(e) {
  this.setState({inLang: e.target.value});
}

handleOutLang(e) {
  this.setState({outLang: e.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className="App-title">Judeo-Arabic Transliterator v 2.0</h1>
      </header>
      <p className="App-intro">
        Enter your Hebrew text below, and select the language to see your transliteration
        </p>
      <Dropdown placeholder={'From'} handleChange={this.handleInLang}/>
      <Dropdown placeholder={'To'} handleChange={this.handleOutLang}/>
      <TextInput handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
      <button onClick={this.handleSet}>Transliterate</button>
      <button onClick={this.handleClear}>Clear</button>
      <TextDisplay textDisplay={this.state.displayValue}/>
    </div>
    )
}
}

export default Home;
```

When I run my dev server, it initially renders just fine. I can choose a dropdown item, which is one of the languages declared in the `langs` variable. However, when I enter some text and click the `Transliterate` button, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. It's referring to line 44: `indices.push(langs.inLang.indexOf(letter));`.

My assumption is that `langs.inLang` is undefined because I updated the state when I selected from the dropdown menu and am now trying to access the state as if it has been updated. However, I'm not positive that this is what I'm doing wrong. If it is, then I'm still a little fuzzy on how to deal with this asynchronicity. I really appreciate any help.

Also, if there are any other critiques of my code, please feel free to share them.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `setState`. you are pushing `langs.inLang.indexOf(letter)`. your variable `langs` doesnt have `inLang`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation to access an object property dynamically.

```
indices.push(langs[inLang].indexOf(letter));
```

Similarly:

```
display.push(langs[outLang][indices[i]]);
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you!